# Displaying photos in PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerapps

Trying to setup a microsoft power app that people in the field use to take photos of signs.  I would like to display those photos in a powerBI dashboard.  Right now i'm sending them from powerapp -> azure SQL-> powerbi and its a little tricky to display.  Any thoughts or best practices.  I feel like SQL may not be the best place to store the photo.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is that you can directly import data through Azure blob Storage where you can send the pictures from powerapps to Azure Blob Storage and upload the data from Blob to Power BI.

[image]